# Calculate the total time difference between each entry and exit for each staff

Tags: r

My data looks like this :

```
Staff Event Time 
123   Entry 07:00 Hrs
123   Exit  08:15 Hrs
123   Entry 08:30 Hrs
123   Exit  11:15 Hrs
123   Entry 11:30 Hrs
123   Exit  15:00 Hrs
124   Entry 07:00 Hrs
124   Exit  09:00 Hrs
124   Entry 09:30 Hrs
124   Exit  14:00 Hrs
```

Now, I need to get the Total In-time and Total Break-time for each staff
(i.e) STAFF ID : 124

1. Total In-time : (Last Exist time-First Entry time) - Total Break-time
                      (14:00 Hrs - 07:00 Hrs) - (09:30 Hrs-09:00 Hrs)
2. Total Break-time : Time between each intermediate Exit and Entry
                        (09:30 Hrs-09:00 Hrs)

I am struggling to get this sorted out. Can anyone kindly help please?

Answer (score 1):

If you format your times as POSIXct, you can subtract them (or use `difftime` directly for control over units). Subtracting them returns `difftime` objects that can be summed:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Staff = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L), 
                     Event = c("Entry", "Exit", "Entry", "Exit", "Entry", "Exit", "Entry", "Exit", "Entry", "Exit"), 
                     Time = c("07:00 Hrs", "08:15 Hrs", "08:30 Hrs", "11:15 Hrs", "11:30 Hrs", "15:00 Hrs", "07:00 Hrs", "09:00 Hrs", "09:30 Hrs", "14:00 Hrs")), 
                .Names = c("Staff", "Event", "Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L
))

df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(Staff) %>% 
    mutate(i = cumsum(Event == 'Entry'),    # add index to allow reshaping
           Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = '%H:%M')) %>%    # parse to datetime
    spread(Event, Time) %>%    # reshape to wide form
    mutate(work_time = Exit - Entry, 
           break_time = lead(Entry) - Exit)

df2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Groups:   Staff [2]
#>   Staff     i               Entry                Exit  work_time break_time
#>   <int> <int>              <dttm>              <dttm>     <time>     <time>
#> 1   123     1 2017-11-06 07:00:00 2017-11-06 08:15:00 1.25 hours    15 mins
#> 2   123     2 2017-11-06 08:30:00 2017-11-06 11:15:00 2.75 hours    15 mins
#> 3   123     3 2017-11-06 11:30:00 2017-11-06 15:00:00 3.50 hours    NA mins
#> 4   124     1 2017-11-06 07:00:00 2017-11-06 09:00:00 2.00 hours    30 mins
#> 5   124     2 2017-11-06 09:30:00 2017-11-06 14:00:00 4.50 hours    NA mins

# now just aggregate
df2 %>% summarise_at(vars(work_time, break_time), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   Staff work_time break_time
#>   <int>    <time>     <time>
#> 1   123 7.5 hours    30 mins
#> 2   124 6.5 hours    30 mins
```